# Azure: can I copy to output directory a file that doesn't reside in my solution directory?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to deploy a Worker Role to Azure.
I can add a file to my project and mark it as:
**Build Action:** Content
**Copy to Output Directory:** Always

When I do this, Visual Studio copies the file into my project directory and then deploys this local copy to the **approot** directory. I'd like the deployment phase to take files from an **external location** and copy that into the output directory.

**Is this possible?**

Note: I do this because I want to deploy files that are in source control under a different directory and I don't want to maintain a different local copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by adding the file as link:

1. Right click your worker role project, choose **Add** > **Existing Item**
2. Choose a file (this can be from a different directory) and make sure you choose **Add As Link**. After clicking Add As Link, the file will show up in your project with something like a shortcut icon.
   [image: Add As Link]
3. Set the Copy to Output Directory property to **Copy always** for that file
4. Package the application. If you check the cspkg, you'll see that the file is in your **approot** folder: [image: AppRoot content]

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware of this option. Is there a way to add an entire directory as a link? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to modify the *.csproj file for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610845/add-as-link-for-folders-in-visual-studio-projects