# Is there a way to add bulk of files to a Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, project, solution

I need to add many source files to a new Visual Studio C++ project.
Probably around 3k+ files, distributed between several nested folders.
I am using Visual Studio 2022.

I tried to drag and drop the files but:

1. It takes forever,
2. I need to do this per each nested folder

Is there a way to add these files, or base folder, which will add all nested files/folders recursively?

Comment: _"Visual Studio project"_ Not sure this makes sense. What type of project is it exactly C#/.NET, or something else? What types of files are they? Can you include some examples in your question?

Comment: You could produce the file list with `dir /b /s > list.txt`, and then use Notepad++ to convert this list into proper XML  for your project file.

Comment: Also, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20033220