# Can I use views in folders linked from other projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have several MVC projects in one solution.

Following this accepted answer: ["Add as Link" for folders in Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610845/add-as-link-for-folders-in-visual-studio-projects), I am attempting to reuse .cshtml views across these proejcts by placing reusable views in a base project. So far, I have set up location formats in the "consuming" projects for the view-engine like this:

```
var locationFormats = new string[]
{
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/Common/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/Common/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
};
```

I have set up a recursive, linked directory in consuming projects' `.csproj` files to include common views like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\..\common.cms\CommonViews\**\*.*">
        <Link>\Views\Common\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

...and all the views are appearing in the consuming projects with the linked-file/cshtml(@) icon, so the paths are correct. For example, the following file is very clearly present in my test consuming project:

```
\Views\Common\Home\Index.cshtml
```

But when I run the project, I'm getting:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Common/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Common/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

**Question**
So I am wondering: is it even possible to link views in this way? What is missing, or what could be inhibiting this from working?

More generally, what about any non-compiled files I'd like to share? Is this technique never going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that this as a known bug in visual studio:    [Linked files in Web Application projects are not deployed properly](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=348886).   This goes back to VS-2008 but still affects VS-2010 and 2012 (not sure about 2013).

A workaround is detailed in this blog-post: 
[Using Linked Files with Web Application Projects](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesdawson/archive/2008/06/03/using-linked-files-with-web-application-projects.aspx).

If you just want the fix wihtout the explanation, you just need to paste the code below at the end of the `.csproj` file for your project (just before the closeing `</project>` tag). This will fix the problem for *any* linked, un-compiled files:

```
 <!--
  ============================================================
  _CopyWebApplication
  MODIFIED: Ignores linked files as part of normal deployment logic.

  This target will copy the build outputs along with the
  content files into a _PublishedWebsites folder.

  This Task is only necessary when $(OutDir) has been redirected
  to a folder other than ~\bin such as is the case with Team Build.
  ============================================================
  -->
  <Target Name="_CopyWebApplication" Condition="'$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'">
    <!-- Log tasks -->
    <Message Text="Copying Web Application Project Files for $(MSBuildProjectName)" />
    <!-- Create the _PublishedWebsites\app\bin folder -->
    <MakeDir Directories="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin" />
    <!-- Copy build outputs to _PublishedWebsites\app\bin folder -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(IntermediateAssembly)"
      DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(AddModules)"
      DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(_SGenDllName)"
      DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.SubFolder)%(Content.RecursiveDir)"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
      Condition="'$(_SGenDllCreated)'=='true'" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetName).pdb"
      DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
      Condition="'$(_DebugSymbolsProduced)'=='true'" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(DocFileItem)"
      DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
      Condition="'$(_DocumentationFileProduced)'=='true'" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath)"
      DestinationFiles="@(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath->'$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\%(Culture)\$(TargetName).resources.dll')"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ReferenceComWrappersToCopyLocal); @(ResolvedIsolatedComModules); @(_DeploymentLooseManifestFile); @(NativeReferenceFile)"
      DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <!-- copy any referenced assemblies to _PublishedWebsites\app\bin folder -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)"
      DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <!-- MODIFICATION HERE: Copy local content files (i.e. non-linked files) recursively to _PublishedWebsites\app\ folder -->
    <Copy Condition=" '%(Content.Link)' == '' "
      SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)"
      DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.RelativeDir)" />
  </Target>



  <!--
  ============================================================
  CopyLinkedContentFiles

  A new target to copy any linked content files into the
  web application output folder.

  NOTE: This is necessary even when '$(OutDir)' has not been redirected.
  ============================================================
  -->
  <Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles">
    <!-- Remove any old copies of the files -->
    <Delete Condition=" '%(Content.Link)' != '' AND Exists('$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.Link)') "
        Files="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.Link)" />
    <!-- Copy linked content files recursively to the project folder -->
    <Copy Condition=" '%(Content.Link)' != '' "
      SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)"
      DestinationFiles="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.Link)" />
  </Target>
  <!-- Override the default target dependencies to -->
  <!-- include the new _CopyLinkedContentFiles target. -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareForRunDependsOn>
      $(PrepareForRunDependsOn);
      _CopyWebApplication;
      CopyLinkedContentFiles;
      _BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput
    </PrepareForRunDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not help in visualstudio 2017 for asp.net core 2.0 mvc problematic as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386941/share-same-layout-cshtml-within-different-projects-of-one-solution-with-asp-net