# Share same _layout.cshtml within different projects of one solution with ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, share, asp.net-core-2.0

We are developing multiple intranet websites with different functionalities. We plan to have a root project (with some basic functionality) from which the user can navigate to the different other projects. 
We plan that all projects of this kind should use the same Layout `_Layout.cshtml`.
To accomplish this we tried to link the `_Layout.cshtml` from the "side-projects" to the root project. We used the VS buildin link method as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19862471/9641435 
The file is linked without any error-message to the path `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. However if we start one of the site-projects the following error message appears:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_Layout' could not be
>   located. The following locations were searched: 
>   /Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml  /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.GetLayoutPage(ViewContext
>   context, string executingFilePath, string layoutPath)

Exception Stack:

> InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_Layout' could not be
>   located. The following locations were searched:
>   /Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.GetLayoutPage(ViewContext
>   context, string executingFilePath, string layoutPath)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+d__18.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+d__14.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+d__22.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+d__21.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+d__26.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__19.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__24.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext
>   context)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next,
>   ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__22.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next,
>   ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__17.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__15.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext()
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext()

We tried to fix it with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24079584/9641435 but inserting that code did not change anything.

We are searching for a solution to fix the described problem or maybe a better aproach to tackle the overall problem.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? If so how did you resolve this?

Comment: unfortunately we did not find a solution

Comment: Maybe this can help but I put up my own thread (keep in mind im using .net core 2.1 not sure if it differs in 2.0) and found a solution to what i was doing which is similar to what you were looking for if i'm not mistaken... Anyways here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231676/net-core-2-1-reusing-layout-throughout-various-projects hopefully this will be of some use for you...

Answer (score 0):

I found that the linked .cshtml files do get copied when the site is built but they are copied to the build bin folder. In my Startup.cs I added this extra area route:-

`if (Env.IsDevelopment())
{
    services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
       options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
    });
}`

your path may differ but if you open up the solution you should be able to adapt this answer to work.

I didn't need this step when publishing to the production web server running IIS using WebPublishMethod MSDeploy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to let the view get copied to the output directory but just have to set the build property to content, resulting in the following code in your csproj file:

`<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\shared\path\to\_Layout.cshtml" Link="Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>`