# How to add-as-link common typescript files in another project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, single-page-application

I'm working on a large single page application developed using TypeScript, KnockoutJS &  RequireJS.

I've two projects 
**Project 1** : Core application, which has all the modules and its files.
**Project 2** : Module project, which is spitted from Project 1.

What I want to do is to include the required `.ts` files in **Project 1**  to **Project 2**

I have a lot of file to be referenced, So i need to add the `.ts` files recursively.

I've tried adding the required `.ts` files using **Add-as-link** option in Visual Studio. Then I tried the ways below to copy them during building the project.

1. **Target Copy** task option in **MSBuid** in the project. As show [here](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx)
2. As show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296185/1470979), using the `<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>` option.

Both didn't work as I expected.

MSBuild task snippet pasted below,

```
 <Project>
   ...
   <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Typescript files from the core project -->
      <TypeScriptCompile Include="..\Project1\Scripts\**\*.ts">
         <Link>scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
         <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </TypeScriptCompile>
      <!-- Typescript files specific to the module project -->
      <TypeScriptCompile Include="scripts\src\module\js\sub-module.ts" />
      <TypeScriptCompile Include="scripts\src\module\js\helpers.ts" />
   </ItemGroup>   
 </Project>
```

Please help me out the correct way to copy the required `.ts` files to the sub project.

Comment: any clue about this issue?